# Nesting Custom Tags in Spring

Tags: spring, namespaces, tags

I am trying create custom namespaces after reading the article at [Custom Namespaces](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.5/reference/extensible-xml.html)

I am able to create simple tags and and able to consume them

for e.g.

```
     <mns:test id="test" port="8003" host="localhost"/>
```

but i am not able to use this tag in another custom tag.

my requirement is like this, i have to create aother custom tag and inject the other simple tag in it.

```
 <mns:test id="test1" port="8003" host="localhost"/>
 <mns:test id="test2" port="8003" host="localhost"/>
 <mns:test id="test3" port="8003" host="localhost"/>

 <mns:instance id="instance" username="XXXXX" password="YYYYYY">
    <mns:test  ref="test1" />
    <mns:test  ref="test2" />
    <mns:test  ref="test3" />
</mns:instance>
```

Please help me..

Comment: Custom namespace config is not for the faint of heart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested elements should be handled manually.

Try to find nested elements using DOM methods and pass them to

```
parserContext.getDelegate().parseCustomElement(e);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ..
I am totally new to  this , can you post some link or Example for me